# Git script to checkout latest version of branch with potential upstream changes

Tags: git

I am attempting to create a script which will fetch the latest version of a given Git branch from upstream, and check it out. However, it need to be able to handle various complications:

- There may be uncommitted changes in the working directory. If so, they should be discarded.
- The given branch may or may not already be the active branch. If not, it should be checked out when the script ends.
- The given branch may or may not already exist locally. If it does not, it should be created and set up to track the upstream branch of the same name.
- The upstream copy may have had its history diverge from the local copy. If so, the upstream history should be kept and the local one discarded.
- If possible, there should be only one operation which queries the upstream server. (Several of my attempts at this ended up having multiple `git pull` or `git fetch` operations.)
- As much as possible, any file whose content does not change between the start and end of the operation should not be touched during it. (E.g. if the old branch history and the new branch history both change a given file in the same ways but use different sequences of commits to do it, unrolling to a most-recent-common-ancestor commit then applying the new history would result in a file which is identical to before but has an updated edit time, thus causing `make` or `docker build` to think it has changed.)

I know how to handle any given one of these cases with some combination of branch-checkouts, resets, and fetches - for instance, if I assume the desired branch is already checked out but its history may have diverged, `git fetch -p ; git reset --hard "origin/${BRANCH}"` will do what I need - but I cannot figure out how to assemble a script which handles all these cases intelligently.

Comment: Why bother with a branch at all? Just extract the commit you like to a directory you designate. If you're allowed to destroy the current work-tree, start with `git clean -dfx` to remove untracked files, then do `git checkout -f <commit-specifier>`. The specifier can be a remote-tracking name or commit hash to get a detached HEAD.

Comment: @torek I want to always be getting the latest commit from a given named branch. I don't want to have to be manually copying commit IDs around.

Comment: Branch names just translate to a commit. If you're using `git fetch` to obtain new commits from some other Git, that updates your remote-tracking names to match their branch names, so that you can easily find their commit hash IDs by names (your remote-tracking names = their branch names).